# Observable not responding to .drive method

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

In my app I have a view that is dependent upon a value in persistent storage. The first time in a session (installing or opening after killing the app) the value is saved to persistent storage and rightfully displayed. However, if I sign out and sign back in (same session) the view does not include my value from persistent storage.

I have reason to believe that there's an issue with my subscription to the 'User' observable in the viewmodel but i'm unsure.

I inserted print statements and found that the closure to the .map function never even triggers in this case. Any thoughts?

MyViewController.swift

```
let myView: MyView
private let viewModel: MyViewModel

override init() {
    ...
    viewModel = MyViewModel(...)
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
    ...
viewModel.potentialEarnings.drive(myView.rx.potentialEarnings).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

MyViewModel.swift

```
let potentialEarnings: Driver<String>

init() {
    ...
    potentialEarnings = User.currentUser(in: getBackgroundContext).map({
      user -> String? in
      let earnings = user.potentialEarnings
      return earnings
    }).unwrap().asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")
}
```

MyView.swift

```
extension Reactive where Base : MyView {
 var potentialEarnings: Binder<String> {
  return Binder(self.base) { myView, potentialEarnings in
    myView.topLabel.text = "Some Text with: \(potentialEarnings)"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your view controller only subscribes upon `viewDidLoad`, but if the subscription is disposed while logging out/in, you are not going to get any more elements. Since `viewDidLoad` only triggers once (assuming you do not recreate the view controller), you will not re-subscribe.

Try adding `.debug("potential earnings driver")`, e.g.:

```swift
viewModel.potentialEarnings
    .debug("potential earnings driver")
    .drive(myView.rx.potentialEarnings)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and check the console for if/when the subscription is disposed.